# Betroffen den Mund verziehen

Tags: single-word-request

Manchmal, wenn Menschen mit anderen Menschen mitfühlen (vor allem Erwachsene mit Kindern), verziehen sie auf eine spezifische Weise den Mund, als würden sie kräftig Luft durch die Nase ausatmen und dabei denken: "Hmm...". Der Gesichtsausdruck, der sich so ergibt, sieht für mich aus wie "das ist aber wirklich schlimm". So eine Mischung aus Bestätigung des empfundenen Leids und Bedauern, während man gleichzeit denkt, dass das jetzt aber doch eine Kleinigkeit war (Kind ist hingefallen und plärrt, als würde ihm ein Arm ausgerissen).

Einen sehr ähnlichen Gesichtsausdruck machen Menschen, wenn sie etwas Unangenehmes aber nicht Allzuschlimmes für sich selbst erwarten. Sie pressen die Lippen aufeinander und schieben sie nach oben in Richtung Nase oder schräg hoch in Richtung Wange. Sie sehen dann aus, als würden sie denken: "das ist jetzt aber total blöd, aber eigentlich auch egal".

Wie bezeichnet man dieses Gefühl?

Betroffenheit ist zu stark.

Comment: Du beschreibst sehr ausführlich den Gesichtsausdruck (bzw. die -ausdrücke), fragst dann aber nach dem Gefühl. Meines Erachtens sind das zwei verschiedene Dinge. Kannst Du vielleicht noch mal genauer schreiben, ob Du einen Begriff für das Gefühl oder den Gesichtsausdruck suchst?

Comment: Die Lippen nach oben schieben ist schon extrem. So eine Schnute kommt wohl eher bei Kindern und vielleicht Frauen vor. Ich würde sie wohl lediglich nach vorne schieben. Wenn ich Dich richtig verstehe hast Du da richtige Wort mit "Bedauern" vielleicht schon erwähnt.

Comment: Könntest du ein Bild von dem Gesichtsausdruck machen / linken? Es gibt da mehrere.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde das erste Gefühl (das der Mutter die ihr hingefallenes Kind tröstet) "einfühlsames Mitgefühl" nennen, dabei ist es unerheblich wie negativ man die Situation selbst empfindet. Den Gesichtsausdruck würde ich mit Ist-ja-nix-passiert-Ausdruck beschreiben, weil mir auch ein besseres Wort fehlt.

Das zweite Gefühl (man muss sich etwas stellen das nicht richtig schlimm aber schon blöd ist) würde ich "resigniertes Schmollen" nennen. Den Gesichtsausdruck "betreten gucken".

Comment: Ist _einfühlsames Mitgefühl_ nicht irgendwie doppelt gemoppelt?

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde das dann als "geheuchelte/heuchlerische Betroffenheit" bezeichnen, obwohl das möglicherweise zu negativ gewertet werden könnte.

Eigentlich trifft es Angelo Fuchs aber mit seinem letzten Ausdruck "betreten gucken" auch angemessen, da man aus Höflichkeit eine Anteilnahme vorgaukelt, die man aber selbst nicht so sehr vertritt, weil es einen nicht direkt betrifft oder man es selbst nicht als so schlimm erachtet.

Answer (score 0):

Du suchst nach Begriffen für etwas, wofür du mit

> hingefallen und plärrt, als würde ihm ein Arm ausgerissen

und

> total blöd, aber eigentlich auch egal

schon sehr schöne Beschreibungen gefunden hast.